# Why does object reference not refer to the intended object?

Tags: c#, reference

I need to change an array cell object which I get from a GetCell method. When I try changing the received object, it does not change the original one.

This is how it looks in code:

```
// this is in MyClass
A[,] arr = new A[100,500];

// this is in main class
MyClass GetAAt(Point p) { return myClass.arr[p.X,p.Y]; }
var a = GetAAt(new Point(23,45));
a = new A(); // this only changes the local `a` but not the arr[23,45]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't changing the received object.
Instead, you're changing a variable, which used to hold the received object, to hold a brand new object instead.

Comment: So how do I do what I want to do?

Comment: You can still solve the problem, you just have to work a bit harder at it.  [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13298796/1159478) as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning new instance to a variable a. You could add a new method to your class

```
void SetAAt(Point p, A a) 
{ 
    arr[p.X,p.Y] = a; 
}
```

and call it like this:

```
Point p = new Point(23,45);
var a = new A();
SetAAt(p, a);
```

P.S. You shouldn't name your array the same name you have for class. Although it is possible, I think it is not a good practice.

Comment: The array's name is `arr`. It's an array of `A`s.

Comment: @SamIam Sorry, didn't mean nothing wrong. It's his way of using Point, I'm trying to change his code. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

both `a` and `arr[23, 45]` are reference types(pointers)

setting `a` to `new A()` only makes it point to a new object.  it doesn't actually change the object it points to.

You'll probably have to add a method to `MyClass` that removes/re-initializes values)

Try adding a method similar to this to your `MyClass`

```
public void ResetAAt(int i, int j)
{
    arr[i, j] = new A();
}
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that `arr` is in another class

Answer (score 0):

What is returned is a reference to the object at that location in the array.  You then set that returned value to a variable.  Changing what that variable references doesn't affect the array in any way.

What you'll need to do is add another layer of indirection:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    private A[,] array;
    private Point position;

    public Wrapper(A[,] array, Point position)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public A Value
    {
        get
        {
            return array[position.X, position.Y];
        }
        set
        {
            array[position.X, position.Y] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to create a wrapper in `GetAAt`, return it, and have that `Wrapper`'s `Value` change and be able to see it reflected in the underlying array.